# App not starting with pm2 after stopping execution

Tags: node.js, debian, pm2

I have an app set to listen to port 66.

First I tried to run it with **sudo node myapp.js** . I was able to access it at the correct url (ip:66). Then I stopped the app (Ctrl+c) and started it with pm2, **sudo pm2 start app.js**. The status is **online**. However, that same url is now inaccessible.

Running sudo pm2 logs while the app is started with pm2 gives me the error EACCESS for port 66. No one else is running the app, and I am sure I am only using one console and killing the node service before starting it with pm2.

Pm2 was installed globally. Server is Debian stretch. Nodejs version is 8.x

I am logging as a normal user and using sudo to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on linux systems normal users are not allowed to listen to ports below 1024. There are several ways around this.

You can change this rule to allow non root users to open such ports. But this is a security risc and is not recommended. So i won't add a link to this solution.

you can also listen to a port that is greater than 1024 and then use a forward rule in your firewall to route port 66 to the port you opened.
https://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/

my (and pm2's) prefered solution is to listen to a port greater than 1024 and use a reverse proxy like nginx to route apps running on that server.
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/pm2-nginx-production-setup

Comment: Thanks, that was a great answer. It turned out I was not the only one to ask this question (I just wasn't googling the right way and could not find an answer). Anyway your tips are very useful.